# No sound using sdl2_mixer from Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, sdl-2, osx-elcapitan

My friend has asked me to test a program for them which uses `sdl2_mixer` for sound. I am using OS X 10.11.

I installed `sdl2_mixer` from Homebrew, but when I run the program, there is no sound.

We have tried `.mp3`, and `.ogg` files, but to no avail.

This warning is displayed, but I don't know if it is connected to the issue:

```
This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon
Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be 
removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with 
version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**:
Apparently this doesn't work anymore. See Mike's comment below.

---

After much searching, I tried reinstalling sdl2_mixer with optional compile options enabled in Homebrew.

First, I removed the original install of `sdl2_mixer` with

```
brew remove sdl2_mixer
```

Then I ran

```
brew --info sdl2_mixer
```

to find out what compile options I could enable.

Finally, I reinstalled `sdl2_mixer` with

```
brew install sdl2_mixer --with-flac --with-fluid-synth --with-libmikmod \
--with-libmodplug --with-libvorbis --with-smpeg2
```

Not all of these compile options will be necessary in every case. You could experiment by enabling just one at a time until you find the one that works in your case.

(I'm pretty sure the depreciation warning mentioned in the question is not relevant to the successful or unsuccessful playback of sound, because the warning still displays even when sound playback is working.)

Comment: This no longer works. Correct solution now is to install sdl2_mixer and to manually edit the brew formula to re-enable mp3 support, then rebuild from source. Source: [https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/issues/299#issuecomment-611681191](https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/issues/299#issuecomment-611681191)